# C#- using a variable in an 'enclosing' local scope?

Tags: c#, wpf, scope, variable-declaration

I am trying to add some new features to a C# application- in particular, trying to replicate some of its behavior, but inside a web browser, rather than in the application, as it currently is.

I am trying to call a method that has been defined in the `Browser.cs` class from inside a method in the `MainWindow.cs` class.

The method is defined in `Browser.cs` with:

```
public partial class Browser : Form{
    public Browser(){
        ...
    }
    public void Browser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
        webKitBrowser1.Navigate("https://google.com");
    }
    ...
}
```

I am then trying to call it from `MainWindow.cs` as follows:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window{
    ...
    public MainWindow(){
        ...
        Browser mBrowser = new Browser();
        Object sender = new Object();
        EventArgs e = new EventArgs();
        mBrowser.Browser_Load(sender, e);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

But, I'm getting a compile error that says:

> A local or parameter named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter

What does this mean? I've never come across this error before- I am using the variable inside the same scope as where it has been declared- what does it mean by 'enclosing local scope'? Is that because I'm using `e` inside the parenthesis for the method call to `mBrowser.Browser_Load(sender, e)`?

Surely, since the call to this method is inside the same scope as where I've defined `e`, it shouldn't be an issue of scope?

I did try performing the call with:

```
mBrowser.Browser_Load(sender, EventArgs e);
```

but this gave me a compile error saying:

> 'EventArgs' is a type, which is not valid in the given context.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here, and what I should be doing to be able to call this method correctly?

Comment: Do you have something like `catch(Exception e)` in the method ?

Comment: You're using two variables called e in the same scope. Normally occurs due to an event being called e, as well as an exception. Change your exception to ex, or rename your event from e to event, and you'll be fine. You can also use [EventArgs.Empty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs.empty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), if you simply need a default EventArgs object with default properties.

Comment: Brilliant- missed that I'd called the `Exception` 'e' as well- thanks very much!

Comment: `mBrowser.Browser_Load(sender, EventArgs e);` isn't valid, you'd have to use `mBrowser.Browser_Load(sender, e);`, just saying

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is pretty clear, you have already defined `e` named variable in your scope, *(Probably in the part of code that you haven't shown)*.

But more importantly, you shouldn't be calling the `Load` event like that, instead **extract the functionality in a separate method and call the method** from your `Load` event and other places.

Like:

```
public void SomeMethodToBeCalledOnLoad()
{
    webKitBrowser1.Navigate("https://google.com");
}

public void Browser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SomeMethodToBeCalledOnLoad();
}

public MainWindow(){
    ...
    Browser mBrowser = new Browser();
    Object sender = new Object();
    EventArgs e = new EventArgs();
    SomeMethodToBeCalledOnLoad();//here
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks- yeah, missed that there was an exception called `e` already there- I've only just started looking at this code.

Comment: don't name your exception `e`, most people name them `ex`. It's not recommended using e since it's used by events (as you just realised.).

Comment: What do you mean by "extract the functionality in a separate method"? You mean the functionality provided by the `Browser_Load()` method? That method was defined in `Browser.cs`, so it already is in a separate method isn't it?

Comment: @someone2088, your functionality in `Browser_Load` is inside an event, *although it is a method too but*, generally it is considered bad practice to explicitly call events. Events are suppose to *occur*. If you want to explicitly call the code inside `Browsers_Load` event, then it is better to extract that code to a separate method and then call that method from `Load` event and other places.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the explanation. The reason I had put the functionality in there, is because when I run the application at the moment, the browser does not load (or at least, is not visible), all I see is the underlying application, which was already there- I'm trying to get that application to display inside a web browser using the functionality provided by `System.Windows.Forms`... any idea how I would do this?

Comment: @someone2088, why can't you use [`WebBrowser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) from WPF ?

Comment: In theory, that's what I'm trying to do- as I mentioned, I've only just started looking at this application, but the `Browser` class that I noted in my OP is using the line `webKitBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.com");` inside the `Browser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` function- however, I don't see anything that actually looks like a browser in the application when I run it...

Comment: The `Browser` class that's there  is defined with: `public partial class Browser : Form{ ... }`. Should that be `: WebBrowser{ ... }` instead of `: Form{ ... }`?

Answer (score 0):

You already have a variable named `e` in the scope.

try to call your method like this

`mBrowser.Browser_Load(this, EventArgs.Empty);`

and the error should go.